# Handling posts and a second kind of markdown content in Gatsby.js

Tags: gatsby

I'm trying to add a second type of content to my gatsby project, 'resources', in addition to posts. **Getting resources okay, but posts have disappeared.**

How what are the steps to set up a second kind of content so I go from posts to posts and (in my case) resources?

Have the following:

in `gatsby-config.js`:

```
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`,
    name: 'pages',
  },
  resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/src/resources`,
    name: 'resources',
  }
}
```

In /templates, I've added `resource.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

export default function Template({data}) {
  const {markdownRemark: resource} = data;
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{resource.frontmatter.title}</h1>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML= {{__html:resource.html}} />
    </div>
  )
}

export const resourceQuery = graphql`
  query ResourceByPath($path: String!) {
    markdownRemark(frontmatter: { path: {eq: $path} }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        path
        title
      }
    }
  }
`
```

my `index.js` (where I want my resources to list) is listing resources. But on `page-2` where I have the same code, I'm getting resources, not posts.

And here is `gatsby-node.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

exports.createPages = ( {boundActionCreators, graphql}) => {
  const {createPage} = boundActionCreators;

  const postTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/post.js`);

  return graphql(`{
    allMarkdownRemark {
      edges {
        node {
          html
          id
          frontmatter {
            path
            title
            date
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }`)
  .then(res => {
    if(res.errors) {
      return Promise.reject(res.errors);
    }

    res.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({node}) => {
      createPage({
        path: node.frontmatter.path,
        component: postTemplate
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: What's the code look like for creating page in gatsby-node.js?

Comment: It might be helpful to look at GraphiQL to understand what's going on with your data http://localhost:8000/___graphql

Answer (score 0):

I will not go into details since the similar question is discussed in [one of the Gatsby issues](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/1634) with solution example.